# How to get the latest value from a row in MySQL db?

Tags: python, mysql

I am new to SQL.
I have a database with 2 columns(username is the primary key) as follows-

```
email                   username

something@mail.com      somename
```

I want to get the latest entries in each column with PyMySQL.
My queries have been-

```
sql = "select top(1) * from userinfo order by username desc"
```

and also

```
sql_command = """SELECT LAST(email) FROM userinfo;"""
```

But every time I get a syntax error saying the query doesn't suit my version.
The version is

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.30, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Comment: If you have only those 2 columns then there is no way of establishing most recent BTW there is no TOP in mysql

Comment: @P.Salmon there are more entries, this is just for example

Comment: Its best to post a representative example.

Comment: @P.Salmon will do in the future, more values are just emails and usernames

Comment: If you don't have a way of establishing a sequence of events , by for example an auto_increment column or date or timestamp then you cannot establish most recent...

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks a lot. Can you suggest a tutorial about how I can do so?

Comment: add an int column, e.g. called 'id', make it the primary_key (or unique index), and set auto_increment on that column.
then you can `ORDER BY \`id\` DESC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: @on8tom Thanks a lot! What will the SQL query look like?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM userinfo ORDER BY \`id\` DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: @on8tom I did that but now I don't get any output.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056897/why-is-the-pymysql-query-not-giving-any-output