# Why is the PyMySQL query not giving any output?

Tags: python, sql, pymysql

My code is as follows-

```
import pymysql
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='',db='form',charset='utf8mb4',cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Create a new record
        sql = "SELECT * FROM info ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1"
        cursor.execute(sql)

finally:
        connection.close()
```

The syntax is correct, but it isn't outputting anything. Terminal simply opens another prompt.
My table is

```
email                  username                       id
name@mail.com          usrname1                        1
name2@mail.com         usrname2                        2
```

The desired output is

```
name2@mail.com              usrname2
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: add result = cursor.fetchone()

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help replace all credential with your own one:

What you are missing in your code is a print statement you are executing a query, but not doing anything with it, take a look at the code that is after the connection.commit() statement. Here is documentation and example on how to use [pyMySQL](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html)

```
import pymysql.cursors


# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='user',
                             password='passwd',
                             db='db',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Create a new record
        sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org', 'very-secret'))

    # connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save
    # your changes.
    connection.commit()

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Read a single record
        sql = "SELECT `id`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `email`=%s"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org',))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        print(result)
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Comment: @AkhibRhast I did this. Now I get an error                                                                                              
    result = cursor.fetchone()
                             ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: @danielli12 as the error message clearly suggest. You are having a TabError. This means that since you might have copy pasted the above code and not written it in your text editor, its is very likely that you have some spaces that are 4 spaces long and some that are 1 tab long, 1 tab = 4 spaces. The error message basically means you are using some tabs, and some spaces somewhere. To fix this issue, ensure that you are consistent through your file in either using 4 spaces only, or tabs only